# Use face aspect ratios to unwrap UV ratio

Tags: uv

On Blender 3.0, I am starting from a texture and making a model planned around its sizes. My texture consists of three parts:

[image]

So I make a cube and scale it so that its sizes are 2:3:5, delete 3 faces, and try to UV Unwrap the remaining object. I was hoping that because my model's aspect ratio matches my texture's aspect ratio, it would do the right thing, but instead, it produces 3 square regions (islands?), and even the orientation is wrong:

[image]

How do I achieve what I want (mapping the "A", "B" and "C" rectangles to the three faces) without fiddling manually with the regions?

I've uploaded my `.blend` file here: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image has not an aspect ratio of 1:1, the UV won't keep its proportions, unless you keep the *Image Texture* node (with the correct image loaded) selected when you unwrap. So select it and unwrap again.

[image]

Actually in your case the problem was that the scale was not 1:1:1, so you first needed to apply the scale in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: sorry there was a word missing, select the Image Texture node selected in the Shader Editor when you unwrap your face

Comment: In your case the scale is not 1:1:1, so you first need to apply the scale in *Object* mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: After applying the scale, indeed the aspect ratio is  now correct! Unfortunately, everything is still off by 90 degrees but I guess I can work around that by rotating my texture image externally.

Comment: yes I don't know if there's an option that allows an automatic 90° rotation when you unwrap, anyway you can rotate it in the UV Editor, then UV > Constrain to Image Bound, choose the 2D Cursor as pivot and scale

Answer (score 0):

With such a simple mesh, you can even enter manually the correct values on every UV Vertex.

[image]